# Mysql - Как выполнить поиск дубликатов по регулярному выражению, или без первых 10 символов?

Tags: mysql

В базе есть колонка auth, в ней находятся аутентификаторы игроков вида.

```
STEAM_1:1:214001995
STEAM_1:0:180255031
STEAM_1:1:191580113
STEAM_1:0:214001995
```

Мне нужно найти все дубликаты без надписи STEAM_(0|1):(0|1): в начале.
Если присмотреться, в примере выше первая и последняя строка одинаковая, за исключением первой цифры, которая не играет тут никакой роли, но именно из-за неё я не могу удалить дубликаты...

Comment: а зачем вам регулярное выражение? удалить первые 10 символов можно просто так -> `substr($str, 10)`. Можно прямо в запросе писать что-то типа такого ->`$q = '... WHERE auth = '.substr($str, 10);`

Comment: @InDevX не учите людей писать уязвимый код с SQL-инъекциями

Comment: Ужас то какой...
`$q = '... WHERE auth = ' . mysql_real_escape_string(substr($str, 10));` или так `$q = '... WHERE auth = ' . (int) substr($str, 10);` так-то я вообще не знаю о каких инъекциях речь если поиск дублей априори не является функцией пользователя и непонятно каким боком он что-то будет/может делать с запросом ... А вообще лучше pdo использовать для этих целей, пора бы уже.

Comment: @InDevX , PHP я бросил 6 лет назад. С чего вы взяли что я его использую если топик называется Mysql...

Comment: Просто для примера написал, подобное в любом языке найти можно; если бы думал что это может быть решением то ответ написал бы

Comment: @InDevX Учитывая что данная функция поддерживается в Mysql, ты можешь дать ответ и он будет почти правильным, он мне скажем так помог, сильно. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html